# limit of function by using derivative

Tags: analysis, limits, functions, derivatives

Let $f: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that  $f^{\prime}(x)= \frac{x^2 - (f(x))^2}{x^2((f(x))^2+1)}$. Prove that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately i even have any idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 2009 Putnam problem.and solution can see somewhere,such as:http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1703577&sid=fa584f5b6ad09063c6880206b67faf11#p1703577